# javaDatabinding-method not called automatically on field change

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am using data binding in my app.I want to set textcolour of a view based on value returned by a method. I tried using below code-

xml

```
android:textColor="@{presenrer.xyz(abc)?@color/cl1:@color/cl2}"
```

viewmodel

```
public Boolean xyz(String abc)
{
..
return bval!=null && bval.getName().equalsIgnorecase(abc);
}
```

But the issue is that when value of bval changes then textcolor is not automatically updated since method is not automatically called when bval changes.How can i update my code to resolve this?

Comment: Show full code of where did you define set `abc`? and how are you changing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When changes was made on some field, you need to call `notifyPropertyChanged(BR.propertyId)` or `notifyChange()` - in that case binding should trigger view to update `textColor` property.

Comment: i tried notifyPropertyChanged ..but that does not call xyz() method again so does not update text colour

Comment: i am setting textcolour based no method NOT based on a field

Comment: @varmashrivastava, as I understand, you have to variables inside your layout: 
    `presenter` and `abc`.
How your code, that change variables, looks like? Could you clarify that moment. Does presenter and abc extends from `BaseObservable` or use `ObservableField`?